# Using string::find to parse a file

Tags: c++

I have a file that I have opened with std::ifstream. I have have a line of code that I want to parse:

```
<image source="tileset/grass-tiles-2-small.png" width="384" height="192"/>
```

And lets say I am interested in "384" found after width="

I am at a loss as how to best extract "384" from that line as the number 384 is not constant at all.

```
void parseFile(const std::string &mfName)
{
    std::ifstream file(mfName);

    std::string line;


    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            std::size_t found = line.find("width");

            if (found != std::string::npos)
            {
                std::cout << found << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "file failed to open" << std::endl;
}
```

Could anyone give me a hint or a link to a good tutorial that covers this?

Comment: Take a look at boost::regex or std::regex if you are using C++11

Comment: Do you have fixed points? Like: do you know at which line your information is, or is the imagename always the same? Do you already use additional libraries in your project, or should it work with plain c++ and stl?

Comment: **http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_regex.html** if you use tr1 you can have alook to this link

Comment: yes, I know or can easily find out at which line my information is located at. and I am using c++11 std

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your file:

```
<image source="tileset/grass-tiles-2-small.png" width="384" height="192"/>
```

And since all you're interested in is the `width`, we should first get the entire line:

```
if (std::getline(file, line))
{
```

Now we need to find `width`. We do that using the `find()` method:

```c++
    std::size_t pos = line.find("width");
```

The string inside `find()` is the value we want to look for.

Once we check if it found this position:

```c++
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
```

We need to put it into a `std::stringstream` and parse out the data:

```
        std::istringstream iss(line.substr(pos));
```

The `substr()` call is used to select a subsequence of the string. `pos` is the position where we found `"width"`. So far this is what is inside the stringstream:

```
 width="384" height="192"/>
```

Since we don't actually care about `"width"` but rather with the number inside the quotes, we have to `ignore()` everything before the quotes. That is done like this:

```
        iss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '"');
```

Now we use the extractor to extract the integer:

```c++
        int width;

        if (iss >> width)
        {
            std::cout << "The width is " << width << std::endl;
        }
```

I hope this helps. Here's a full example of the program:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void parseFile(const std::string& mfName)
{
    std::ifstream file(mfName);
    std::string line;

    if (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        auto pos = line.find("width");
        if (pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::istringstream iss(line.substr(pos));
            int width;

            if (iss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '"') &&
                iss >> width)
            {
                std::cout << "The width is " << width << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to understand igonre()

after:
    std::istringstream iss(line.substr(pos));
we have:
    width="384" height="192"/>

but after:
    if (iss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '"') && iss >> width)

we get the number.
I thought ignore would, well ignore all char's up to and including '"'

how come we end up with just a number and not go from:
     width="384" height="192"/>

Comment: @user2299044 Inside the `if` statement, the `ignore()` call runs first. It will ignore (or rather "skip") all the characters up until and including `"`. When the `ignore()` call finishes, this is what will be the remaining content: `384" height="192"/>`. When `iss >> width` runs, it will extract the integer until it finds a non-integral character, namely the other `"`.

Comment: quite clever. coming from python I expected to have to do what iss >> width does manually in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Parse strings using a regex parser. As you are doing C++, include the `<regex>` header, and use the function `regex_search` to match results. The results go into a `smatch` object, which is iteratable.

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Also see: [Retrieving a regex search in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908534/retrieving-a-regex-search-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd use an XML library (if this is actually XML). This is one of the things you certainly don't want to reinvent but *reuse*! :)

In the past, I've successfully used [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) for smaller projects. Or google "c++ xml library" for alternatives.

Comment: I know there are library's I could use, but I am doing this more as a means of learning. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [*`Boost-Regex`*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html), you can use something like following in your function

```
/* std::string line = "<image source= \
     \"tileset/grass-tiles-2-small.png\" width=\"384\" height=\"192\"/>";
*/

boost::regex expr ("width=\"(\\d+)\"");
boost::smatch matches;

if (boost::regex_search(line, matches, expr)) 
{
    std::cout << "match: " << matches[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Would using regex be the recommended way to parse a file that includes many lines like the one I have mentioned?

Comment: @user2299044 First of all I'd use a scripting language to do that, but if C++ is really the need here, `boost::regex` would be one of the preferred option, and yes you can use it for many lines too, in your case it will be line-by-line. You can refer the online document for any regex for for help, it will be all most same for boost too