# Parse (replace) in C++ std::string

Tags: c++

I have a "custom" string that has the following format. Example:

```
std::string MyString = "RndOrder%5d - RndCustomer%8s - RndHex%8x";
```

I would like to replace/parse the string:

- the `%5d` (%NUM_d) would be replaced with a random 5-digit decimal
- the `%8s` (%NUM_s) would be replaced with a random 8-chars
- the `%8x` (%NUM_x) would be replaced with a random 8-digit hexadecimal

Is there any function that helps me parse those "special marks"? Not sure if I would have to parse the string char by char and check for every possible combination.

Comment: No, there isn't. Not in C++.

Comment: Sure, there is in C++. Look up Boost.Spirit.

Comment: Or string::substr, which gets you part of the way there at least.

Comment: Not sure I understand. What's wrong with `printf` for this case?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22617209/4928642

Comment: @Robin, printf doesn't generate any random things according to format.

Comment: You can use [std::sprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Answer (score 2):

If the format can be variant (not always the fixed 3 arguments: `%5d`, `%8s` and `%8x`) and you want to be flexible in that manner, you should write your own implementation for that.

Assuming that count defined after `%` is a general digit (not only 5 or 8) you could try using the [std::regex_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) or [std::regex_match](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/) to find the actual mnemonics you are looking for. For example your expression could look like `%\d+[dsx]`

Then you should parse it to find the `COUNT` and `type` and substitute with a random number acquired with the desired [generator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/).
To parse you could try updating the above expression to `%(\d+)([dsx])` and capturing groups.

A sample parse implementation for your case could look like this:

```
std::string text = "RndOrder%5d - RndCustomer%8s - RndHex%8x";
auto reg = std::regex("%(\\d+)([sdx])");
std::smatch match;
while (std::regex_search(text, match, reg))
{
    const auto& full = match.str(); // in 1st iter contains "%5d"
    const auto& count = match.str(1); // in 1st iter contains "5"
    const auto& type = match.str(2); // in 1st iter contains "d"
    // further processing: type conversion, number generation, string replacement

    text = match.suffix().str();
}
```

For implementation example with search and group capturing you can also check out another question: [Retrieving a regex search in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908534/retrieving-a-regex-search-in-c)

Comment: `[dsx]`, not `[d,s,x]`. Also it would be right to add `+`: `\d+`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. In that case you could accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok, assuming that you're actually asking about string parsing here (and not random number/data generation)... have a look at this:

```
int iRandom1 = 12345;       // 5-digit decimal
int iRandom3 = 0x12345678;  // 8-digit hexadecimal
char cRandom2[9] = "RandomXY\0";  // Don't forget to NULL-terminate!
std::string sFormat = "RndOrder%5d - RndCustomer%8s - RndHex%8x";

char cResultBuffer[500];  // Make sure this buffer is big enough!

std::sprintf( cResultBuffer, sFormat.c_str(), iRandom1, cRandom2, iRandom3 );
std::string MyString = cResultBuffer;  // MyString = "RndOrder12345 - RndCustomerRandomXY - RndHex12345678";
```

Comment: Where is string parsing in this answer? How did you detect formats of the arguments and number of digits/chars in generated values?

Comment: Thanks! But that's for a fixed "format". I would like to accept other "sFormat" strings, like "rnd_id_%6d"

Answer (score 1):

It's a candidate for `std::snprintf` (c++14), but take care to request the correct buffer size in one call, allocate a buffer and then format the string into the buffer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

template<class...Args>
std::string replace(const char* format, Args const&... args)
{
    // determine number of characters in output
    auto len = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, format, args...);

    // allocate buffer space
    auto result = std::string(std::size_t(len), ' ');

    // write string into buffer. Note the +1 is allowing for the implicit trailing
    // zero in a std::string
    std::snprintf(&result[0], len + 1, format, args...);

    return result;
};

int main() {
    auto s = replace("RndOrder%5d - RndCustomer%8s - RndHex%8x", 5, "foo", 257);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
RndOrder    5 - RndCustomer     foo - RndHex     101
```